# Как отправить сообщение на почту, при этом остаться на странице?

Tags: html, python, django

После отправки сообщения меня перенаправляет на другую страничку, естественно я сделал так сам, но по другому не получается.
Вот код, пользовался и рендером чтобы отрисовать страничку заново, но это не то. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы страничка возвращалась к предыдущей, либо чтобы просто обновлялась?

```
def send_email(request):
   subject = 'Новая заявка!'
   message = 'Имя: ' + request.POST.get('name_field') + '\n' + 'Телефон\Email: ' + request.POST.get(
    'name_field2') + '\n' + 'Cообщение: ' + request.POST.get('name_field3')
   email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
   recipient_list = ['warglok@gmail.com', ]
   send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
   return HttpResponse("Successful")
```

Сейчас просто выводится на результат HttpResponse("Successful")

Answer (score 1):

С помощью js и ajax

```js
$(".btn-submit-js").on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('.form');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: form.serialize();,
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я не много не понимаю куда этот код вставить, в тег скрипт странички, которая открывается или куда-то в другое место?

Comment: На страницу с формой. Ссылочку если отправите, то попробую помочь

Comment: @DobryKisik лучше отделить. Создать файл , например js.js в него вставить данный скрипт, подключить его (по аналогии с подключением стилей css). Далее надо будет подключить jquery (либо скачать библиотеку либо подключить вот так `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> ` в теге `<head>`).

Comment: Встави в базовый HTML от которого наследуются все другие, вставил такую ссылочку <script src="{% static "js/reboot.js" %}"></script>, в этом доке весь код Js, который вы мне сбросили, jquery подключено было. Не подскажете что я мог упустить, может я что-то забыл вызвать?

Comment: Как минимум проверить наличие селекторов в отправляемой форме `.btn-submit-js` на кнопке и  `.form` у формы. Либо изменить в скрипте на нужные. Вообще хорошо бы ссылочку на то что делаете узреть )

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов ну еще по идее надо будет немного вьюх переписать

Comment: согласен, но вопрос изначально в том как отправить )

Comment: Честно сказать всё перепробовал, не могу понять решение этой задачки(
Ссылку не могу дать, т.к. не заливал на гитхаб. В интернете сайта тоже нет, вот это последняч деталь, которую мне осталось доделать, прежде чем я выложу свой первый сайт) Сейчас попробую добавить больше информации